# Is there any way to Copy file which is open in tab in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

There are hundreds of files in my android project. I have one file open in tab and want to copy this file to another project. But right clicking on the file tab has no option to copy the file which I can see from the file explorer of android studio. Is there any easy way to copy without navigating to that file from explorer view or any easy way to navigate to that file on explorer?

[Menu after right clicking on a tab which I want to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43ENE.png)

Comment: Why not use the project file structure tab?

Comment: I can but still I have to navigate through the structure tab, right? I want to skip that if possible cause there are lots of packages and files.

Comment: There is option in project structure scroll from source (round shaped icon). It will take to file location in project structure (File which is selected in workplace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`easy way to navigate to that file on explorer` is this icon:
[image]

It will navigate to current open file in the project explorer